# Executing 3 commands using one start command on the Windows prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to execute 3 commands one by one with using one `start` statement. One way to do it is to create a `bat` file with these commands and calling that bat file with start. 
Another way to execute is separate those commands with `&&` as below.

```
start cmd1 && start cmd2
```

But, here `cmd1` and `cmd2` are executed in two separate command windows. I want to execute the `cmd2` in the same window where `cmd1` is executed.

I also used `call` for `cmd2`, but then `cmd2` is executed in the window from where `start` is
called.

Is there any way to do it without using bat files?

Comment: you want _three programs_ running in the _same window_ at the _same time_? Nice thought ....

Comment: I've played with `for /f in (command)` and `cmd /k` but drew a blank. Are secondary batch files (in `%temp%` should be easy enough) really so bad? :)

Comment: @Endoro, not at the same time. I want to run three programs sequentially in the same window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is:

start "Mydummywindowtitle" cmd /c Command1 ^& Command2 ^& Command3

You just have to escape the ampersand. In cmd.exe, the caret character is used for escaping.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know the escape character in DOS.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the /B flag -- which tells Start to not open a new window but instead run the command in the background of the same window.

Remember though:  You are still starting a new instance of start each time.  I'm assuming this is what you intend, however.

Comment: `start` with /B option with `cmd2` is just behaving like `call` command as explained in question. But I need to execute `cmd2` where `cmd1` is executed.